Minio Web GUI is working properly in Kubernetes
Hi I am trying to run minio in my kubernetes env so followed the following guide.
https://medium.com/@kapincev/easy-guide-setting-up-minio-with-microk8s-kubernetes-321048d901ac
but then i am getting following error:

how to resolve it?
